# How to sync To Do app in Ubuntu Laptop and Desktop?

Tags: 22.04, sync

How to sync To Do app in Ubuntu 22.04 Laptop and Desktop?

Comment: This question can be broken down to 2 questions: 1. How to sync files and folders over LAN between two Ubuntu computers? 2. Where does the gnome To Do store it's data? Both these questions have been answered here before.

Comment: @This should actually be an answer...with the respective links though